# context path for file upload without HttpRequest in REST application

Tags: file-upload, spring-mvc

I am building REST application. I want to upload a file and I want to save it for example in /WEB-INF/resource/uploads

How can I get path to this directory ? My Controller looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/house/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateHouse(House house, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
    try {
        String fileName = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        if (file.getSize() > 0) {
                inputStream = file.getInputStream();

                fileName =  "D:/" + file.getOriginalFilename();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

                int readBytes = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
                while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    model.addAttribute("step", 3);
    this.houseDao.update(house);
    return "houseAdmin";
}
```

Second question...what is the best place to upload user files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/WEB-INF` is a bad place to try to store file uploads. There's no guarantee that this is an actual directory on the disk, and even if it is, the appserver may forbid write access to it.

Where you should store your files depends on what you want to do with them, and what operating system you're running on. Just pick somewhere outside of the webapp itself, is my advice. Perhaps create a dedicated directory

Also, the process of transferring the `MultipartFile` to another location is much simpler than you're making it out to be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/house/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateHouse(House house, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile srcFile, Model model) throws IOException {
    File destFile = new File("/path/to/the/target/file");
    srcFile.transferTo(destFile); // easy!

    model.addAttribute("step", 3);
    this.houseDao.update(house);
    return "houseAdmin";
}
```

Comment: that is great. Much shorter, much simpler, much better :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store files in `/WEB-INF/resource/uploads`. This directory is either inside your WAR (if packaged) or exploded somewhere inside servlet container. The first destination is read-only and the latter should not be used for user files.

There are usually two places considered when storing uploaded files:

1. **Some dedicated folder**. Make sure users cannot access this directory directly (e.g. anonymous FTP folder). Note that once your application runs on more than one machine you won't have access to this folder. So consider some form of network synchronization or a shared network drive.
2. **Database**. This is controversial since binary files tend to occupy a lot of space. But this approach is a bit simpler when distributing your application.

Comment: yes I know that I can use DB but I don`t want to. I wan`t to upload user files that will be displayed on the page (mostly) images. So I should create directory like /var/www/project/user_uploads and throw files from there and upload there.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't `/var/www/` directory accessible from the browser? This means every user will be able to access any fil without your control. This might be an advantage (raw Apache access is fast), but also a security hole if you want to apply some stricter security model.

Comment: true that but I can restrict access only to this directory from apache. There will be only image files so if someone access it there won`t be a big drama. But I agree that your example of anonymous FTP folder is better

Comment: Tomasz would you be so nice and linked me to some sample how to do a proper managment with files ? That`s sad but I have a problem with uploading files and displaying them on site :(

Comment: i think that my problem is in restful application. When I want to display and image from the local hdd I get 404. How should I configure it ?

Comment: Please open a separate question, this is not related to the current one.